# Android coverflow

Tags: java, android, mobile, coverflow

I'm writing an application for android and would like to have an `itunes` like coverflow preview.
Is there anything in the api that I can use or do I have to build it from scratch?

Comment: Cover Flow is [patented](http://www.engadget.com/2010/04/08/apple-granted-design-patent-on-cover-flow/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in coverflow widget, the closest thing is probably the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget. Still I'd be surprised if someone hadn't tried something of the sort yet, and you might find some code floating around the internet. Google has some mentions of coverflow on Android, though I haven't checked it out in any detail.

Comment: There is a Coverflow view in the music application. But I haven't figured out if they use a standard view that is just not documented of if they wrote their own.

Comment: Gallery is deprecated. You should use either HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager.

Answer (score 33):

I've created a basic coverflow widget it can be found here:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html

Comment: Thanks taf. Your application is awesome. 
Can you prepare an application on page curl animation in android which is in iPhone.
I would be very thankful to you if you help me out in this.

Comment: But this is not consistent. I have tried this, but it leads to VM outOfMemory error. This is because bitmap takes too mush of memory

Comment: I guess the link is no more valid...the domain has expired or something like that...

Comment: Hello @taf, can u give me a tip how to do extra zoom on centered image in coverFlow on click? I analyzed code but not sure which parameter I should change to achieve it.. :S I know that cenetered image is already zoomed but I want to achieve following effect:

centered view is zoomed but on click it zoom even more (just that one), on one more click it goes back to normal zoomed level defined by CoverFlow parameters.. 

thank u a lot for advice, I found very useful ur code of CoverFlow.. Cheers

Comment: This widget can no longer be used as Gallery is deprecated

Comment: It works great. I just wanted to know if it's possible to increase the height of the coverflow. There was a block of code in your sample that set the layout params (height to 500) but was commented. I tried uncommenting it to set the height, but the application crashed. Could you please guide us in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Well I figured this out. I just changed the layout params of the imageView in createReflectedImages function, and it worked. Thanks for the great example. Cheers.

Comment: Very nice except the pictures wont straighten out in the center.

Answer (score 5):

This is not provided by default however there is:

http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Answer (score 1):

For latest versions (3.1+) of the sdk there is a sample provided during Google I/O 2 years ago. It shows a 3D coverflow which could be an alternative to a coverflow. (It's widely used in apps like Google Music and News app).

Demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2caXMF-ud8).

Source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip).

Comment: This is developed using the Renderscript graphics API which is now deprecated in Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

I made a coverflow widget from scratch. It doesn't use any deprecated components.
You can find it here:
http://applm.github.io/ma-components/