# implement a coverflow UI in an Android web application

Tags: android, css, 3d, transform, coverflow

I am trying to build a coverflow UI on an Android web application using HTML,CSS, JavaScript and some images.

CSS 3D transforms, which are supported in Safari sine 2009 and on the iPhone since version 2.0, is not supported well on the Android. worse then that, the implementation is buggy on Android 2.1 and Android 2.2, and in each version in a different way.

**Any idea how can I build a coverflow UI on an Android web application using HTML,CSS, JavaScript and some images without CSS 3D transforms?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725496/android-coverflow

Comment: This is a native application. I am looking for a web based application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for textured 3D transformations without the use of CSS 3D or plugins, look no further than Canvas, the HTML element present on most cutting-edge browsers. There are already 3D libraries that take advantage of this, like [K3D](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/canvask3d/k3d_test.html).

On the flip side, you can use dynamic HTML and pre-rendered images at different angles. For a 3D effect without rotations, simply implement a basic 3D rendering formula, such as this one:

Point's X position on the screen = position X in pixels / distance away + half of the screen width

Point's Y position on the screen = position Y in pixels / distance away + half of the screen height

Comment: Regular canvas only supports affine transformations not 3D transforms. Affine transforms in CSS work fine in Android. WebGL is the extension for Canvas that makes it work with 3D transforms.